# How to define a nullable and unique column inside CREATE TABLE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I had a table defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  -- ...
  MY_COLUMN VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

This definition, however, caused problems when having `MY_COLUMN` as `NULL` in multiple rows, so I changed it to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  -- ...
  MY_COLUMN VARCHAR(100) 
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_my_column_not_null
ON dbo.MY_TABLE(MY_COLUMN)
WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NOT NULL;
```

This solved that problem, but I needed to create a constraint outside the `CREATE TABLE` expression, since it didn't allow me to put the `WHERE` inside it.

Is there a way to get this functionality without writing code outside the `CREATE TABLE` expression? Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  -- ...
  MY_COLUMN VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE ALLOW NULLS
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create an index (including filtered `UNIQUE` indexes) within the `CREATE` table statement, but you can't define it along side the column, you have to define the `INDEX` specifically:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (MyColumn varchar(100) NULL,
                          INDEX UQ_MyColumn UNIQUE (MyColumn) WHERE MyColumn IS NOT NULL);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d118d73c72566399fcaa423d88bb0b5e)

Comment: Interesting, I did check the `CREATE TABLE` grammar. But `<table_index>` doesn't mention a `WHERE` clause. Must be out of date! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I can only assume that it's implicit included in the `| [ <table_index> ] }` section, @MartinSmith . But I agree, it's not in the `<table_index> ::=` section. I might send a revision if I get the chance.

Comment: [Pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/7628) sent, @MartinSmith .